# JQuery scrollTop equality not working when scrolling too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing an infinite scroll with jquery and i'm trying to detect when the bottom of the main `div` reach the bottom of the browser window.
My problem is that in my code if the user scrolls too fast, the equality is not fired on the code. How to prevent this?

The code `$(this).scrollTop() === exactPoint` not fires when the user scrolls too fast.

Here is a fiddle with an example of how i'm doing the behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/CCwYm/1/

I have googled and searched here and can't found something that help me.

Comment: use `$(this).scrollTop() <= bottom` to detect current point

Comment: Use `>` so you don't miss the exact point?

Comment: But what if i want to detect the exact point with the `===`?

Comment: (1) Infinite scroll is horrible UX (2) Should you have a use case for it, you generally start loading the next window of data before the bottom, for instance when you get to 20% from the bottom.

Comment: `===` what does it does there? check your fiddle using `==` http://jsfiddle.net/CCwYm/47/

Comment: The problem is probably not with `scrollTop()` it is probably because of overlapping `onScroll` events (which I assume you are calling). Will you post your full event code?

Comment: the fiddle has the entire code of the event.. i don't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing an infinite scroll page with jQuery and if your problem is that you can't properly detect the current bottom of the page before new content changing height to the document do try something like this (based on the code from your fiddle)

```js
console.log($(document).height());
console.log($(window).height());
console.log($(document).height() - $(window).height())
var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

$(document).scroll(function(){
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < bottom) {
        console.log("scrolling");     
    } else {
        alert("bottom"); 
        $('.test').clone().appendTo( "body" );  
        bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    }
});
```

```css
.test{
 width: 100px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: If i change the `===` with the `==` the code works the same.. if you check the console under developer tools of the explorer, you can see that if i scroll to quick the equality doesn't get fired.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy i run the snippet in jsfiddle did not work with `===` it worked fine with `==`

Comment: The problem with your fiddle is that your code is fired when the bottom of the document is reached... and there's no possibility to keep scrolling, so the bottom on the console will always be shown because of that. My code must detect the bottom of the `div` reaching the bottom of the window.. so, if i scroll too quick and pass that point then is not analyzed.

Comment: ok i think i get better what you mean... @Phoenix_uy yes but lazy load scrolling will add new height always just a bit before hitting current bottom. Either pass the div-bottom if i may name it like that before that limit.

Comment: i am editing my answer but your question was incomplete. @Phoenix_uy